# How to run OpenMP parallel in android native code?

Tags: android-ndk, openmp

I am currently using OpenMP's #pragma's to distribute Android app's native code for loop to parallel threads as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(variable1) shared(variable2) shared(variable3) private(array_1) private(array_1) private(array_1)
{
    LOG(INFO) << "Running inside thread:  " << omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma omp for
    for (int c = 1; c <= itrloopLim; c++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am compiling with `-fopenmp`, but after installing the .apk, the app crashes on runtime with the below error:

```
12-06 23:30:58.700 32133 32314 W System.err: TensorFlowLite: failed to load native library: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__kmpc_end_critical" referenced by "/data/app/org.mlperf.inference-aKoP_FhySRDbKCU5EeEcmQ==/lib/arm64/libmlperf_jni.so"...
12-06 23:30:58.700 32133 32314 E lperf.inferenc: No implementation found for void org.mlperf.inference.MLPerfDriverWrapper.nativeDeleteBackend(long) (tried Java_org_mlperf_inference_MLPerfDriverWrapper_nativeDeleteBackend and Java_org_mlperf_inference_MLPerfDriverWrapper_nativeDeleteBackend__J)
12-06 23:30:58.701 32133 32314 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: MLPerf.Worker
12-06 23:30:58.701 32133 32314 E AndroidRuntime: Process: org.mlperf.inference, PID: 32133
12-06 23:30:58.701 32133 32314 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.mlperf.inference.MLPerfDriverWrapper.nativeDeleteBackend(long) (tried Java_org_mlperf_inference_MLPerfDriverWrapper_nativeDeleteBackend and Java_org_mlperf_inference_MLPerfDriverWrapper_nativeDeleteBackend__J)
12-06 23:30:58.701 32133 32314 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.mlperf.inference.MLPerfDriverWrapper.nativeDeleteBackend(Native Method)
12-06 23:30:58.701 32133 32314 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.mlperf.inference.MLPerfDriverWrapper.access$000(MLPerfDriverWrapper.java:23)
12-06 23:30:58.701 32133 32314 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.mlperf.inference.MLPerfDriverWrapper$Builder.useMLBackend(MLPerfDriverWrapper.java:205)
12-06 23:30:58.701 32133 32314 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.mlperf.inference.RunMLPerfWorker.handleMessage(RunMLPerfWorker.java:102)
12-06 23:30:58.701 32133 32314 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-06 23:30:58.701 32133 32314 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-06 23:30:58.701 32133 32314 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
12-06 23:30:58.703  1439  1467 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity org.mlperf.inference/.MLPerfEvaluation


12-06 23:30:58.707  1439  1585 I ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package org.mlperf.inference u0
12-06 23:30:58.715  1439  1584 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
```

Comment: The first line there is saying that you don't have an OpenMP runtime installed on the machine... (you likely need libomp.so).

Answer (score 1):

Having tried including `-fopenmp -static-openmp` flags to my app's build.gradle file (`ndk 23.1.7779620`), I encountered the following error:

> warning: argument unused during compilation: '-static-openmp' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

as others mentioned.

I managed to solve the issue by following the linking steps included in the [android ndk test code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/tests/device/openmp/CMakeLists.txt). So, instead of adding the relevant flags to my build.gradle file, I added the following to the external native build CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(mycppLib -fopenmp -static-openmp )
target_compile_options(mycppLib -fopenmp)
```

I can confirm that the static libomp.a is compiled with the application, which makes shipping the app with libomp.so unnecessary, as is expected with the inclusion of the `-static-openmp` flag.
Note that without the `-static-openmp` flag, an application will likely crash on startup when it fails to load libomp.so.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same issue, no error in compilation but the app crashes immediately on startup.

It turns out you need to use the "-static-openmp -fopenmp" flags. Your build gradle has to look like this basically :

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON"
            cppFlags "-static-openmp -fopenmp"
        }
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get `clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-static-openmp' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]`. I'm using NDK version 23, so clang should be new enough to support this. Any idea?

Comment: I encountered the same issue `clang-12: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-static-openmp' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] ` when compiling with NDK23.  But instead of "-fopenmp" with error `cannot find libomp.so`, the executable run normally on android device.